# Custom html into GTM for Salesforce

Tags: gtm

I'm adding a mini form on my website.  The form includes a dropdown field called "Business Type" where you can pick your industry.

I'm trying to make industry show up in my leads detail information.  Below is my custom html set up in Google Tag Manager.  Any idea of what I need to add to the html below to include this new field?

```
function() {
 var bizSize = '';
 var signupType = "Self Sign Up";
 if ({{Page URL}}.includes('candidate_token')) {
   bizSize = document.querySelector('#sign-up-form-business_size').value;
   signupType = 'Mini-Form Signup';
 } else if (window.senderInfo) {
   bizSize = window.senderInfo.business_size;
 }
 if ({{Page Hostname}}.match(/XXX\.XXXXXX\.com/i)) {
   
   // Production
   return {
    "oid": "00D6A000002kdrm",
    "00N2G00000B9tKq": {{dlv - user_id}},
    "00N2G00000B9tKp": {{JS - Google Analytics ClientID}},
    "00N2G00000B9tKr": "1",
    "00N6A00000Mkk2x": {{ck - ga_source}},
    "00N6A00000Mkk2w": {{ck - ga_medium}},
    "00N6A00000Mkk2u": {{ck - ga_campaign}},
    "00N6A00000Mknci": signupType,
    "00N6A00000Mkncn": bizSize
   }
  
 } else {
   
   // Dev / QA
   return {
    "oid": "00D1h000000IiFL",
    "00NL0000008PVOA": {{dlv - user_id}},
    "00NL0000008PXiq": {{JS - Google Analytics ClientID}},
    "00NL0000008PXiv": "1",
    "00N6A00000Mkk2x": {{ck - ga_source}},
    "00N6A00000Mkk2w": {{ck - ga_medium}},
    "00N6A00000Mkk2u": {{ck - ga_campaign}},
    "00N6A00000Mknci": signupType,
    "00N6A00000Mkncn": bizSize
   }  
   
 }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm seeing a lot of lookup fields to a custom object there, at least if those "00N" values are from your Salesforce instance.
Aside from that, though, I'd be looking at Salesforce's "Web-to-Lead" section of Setup for help with formatting. For example:

```
<label for="industry">Industry</label>
  <select  id="industry" name="industry">
  <option value="">--None--</option>
  <option value="(insert first visible picklist value here)">(insert first visible picklist *label* here)</option>
  <option value="(insert second visible picklist value here)">(insert second visible picklist *label* here)</option>
  (and so on)
  </select>
```